# Execute sonar runner locally

Tags: java, sonarqube

Is it possible to execute sonar-runner locally for debugging purposes?

Comment: Are you trying to step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it possible, it is actually one of the "recommended" ways of running sonar. By locally I'll assume you want to have both the Sonar Server and the project to analyse on your machine. Install Sonar, build your plugin using Maven and copy it to sonar plugins directory, then launch the runner using the command line, as explained [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner) and [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Runner).